# How to check position of UI elements in pixel in xaml app while debugging

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to check the visually positions of xaml UI elements in the app that is launched in debug mode. I do not want to check it in designer for some reason. Is there a way? This will be very similar to how html elements are inspected in browser. Do we have something similar for UWP apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check the visually positions of xaml UI elements in the app that is launched in debug mode.

Sure, you could use the [TransformToVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual?view=winrt-19041) method to get the position of this UIElement, relative to its parent.

**For example**

```
 var ttv = polyline1.TransformToVisual(canvas);
 Point position = ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: I want to see the position of the element to visually inspect like we do for html development. Do we have a way to do that in xaml?

Comment: You could check the element position with xaml [designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I am not able to do that because I am loading the control which is implemented in another dll.

Comment: Have you [Inspected XAML properties while debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2019) with live visual tree tool

Comment: Yes I did inspect XAML properties while debugging. Earlier I was not able to inspect all of the elements. But somehow now I am. So this is good. But I was looking for an option to see these properties of layout on the app itself, but I guess they are not available there. But surely this inspect option helps. Thanks Nico.